# Custom TableViewCell autolayout issue upon orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom UITableViewCell class like this:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
  var mainText:UILabel = UILabel()
  var detailText:UILabel = UILabel()

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.contentView.addSubview(mainText)
    self.contentView.addSubview(detailText)

    self.updateCellConstraints()
  }

  fileprivate func updateCellConstraints() {
    self.mainText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.detailText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.detailText.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    let margins = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    self.mainText.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.mainText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    self.detailText.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainText.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    self.detailText.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    self.detailText.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    self.detailText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I dequeue it and set some custom properties on `mainText` and `detailText` and finally set an `accessoryType` which is a disclosure indictor.

Now the problem. Everything works well in portrait mode but when I switch to landscape on an iPad, my cell is centered (i.e. left and right areas are left blank and cell is centered, `maintext` and `disclosureIndicator` are still apart but UI doesn't look good). How do I get rid of this?

I want my cell to work perfectly fine like it is in portrait mode. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: post screenshots of both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of readable content guides that Apple added in iOS9.

Just do:

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

or if you deploy to pre iOS9:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
}
```

More on this topic [Readable Width of Table View Cells](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/readable-width-of-table-view-cells/)

[image: Both modes side by side]

Comment: Great, you can also accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark if this is all you needed :)